# how could the answer be '11' about len(str(3.154155151000))?

Tags: python, floating-point, string-length

```
len(str(3.154155151000)) #11 ???
len(str(154155151000))  #12
```

In my opinion, the answer of `len(str(3.154155151000))` would be `14`.
I thought the answer is `14` that might be include `3` and point.
But the actual result is `11`
How could it be `11`?

Comment: So, what is: `str(3.154155151000)`?

Comment: Slightly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: @quamrana Very slightly :)

Comment: @Barmar: Yes, only as far as representation goes ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The parameters passed into a method gets evaluated before they enter the method. So the `3.154155151000` gets evaluated before `str(3.154155151000)`, hence `3.154155151000` becomes just `3.154155151` by the time it gets converted to a string.